# How to install Livestreamer --- super n00b terminal question

Tags: terminal, install

I am just trying to install [Livestreamer](http://docs.livestreamer.io/install.html) on my MacBook but it looks like the only way to do so is with:

```
# easy_install -U livestreamer
```

I entered this in the terminal and hit enter...but nothing happened. Is that what I'm supposed to do? I know it's a total n00b question but I can't find any help on installing Livestreamer for Mac via Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` is usually used in shell command samples to show the shell prompt and should not be entered. As it is also the comment indicator, the command you've entered just does *nothing*.

Make sure you are logged into an account with Administrator privileges to run the command. Then run

```
easy_install -U livestreamer
```

or (only if the above gives you "access denied" errors)

```
sudo easy_install -U livestreamer
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the "#" let it try to do it's thing, but even as an admin I recieve this error message: "[Errno 13] Permission denied ... perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory..." Why would this be a problem if I'm an admin?

Comment: sudo easy_install -U livestreamer

Comment: First time you sudo you'll get a message telling you to be careful - this is normal. Enter your normal user password. sudo runs commands with elevated priviledges.

Comment: It worked for me without `sudo`, maybe your phyton installation is different than mine.

Comment: FYI, easy_install is typically not recommended nowadays (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30408520/992504 for an explanation). Instead, use pip: `pip install livestreamer` (or `sudo pip install livestreamer` if you get a permission error)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012246/why-is-python-easy-install-not-working-on-my-mac

You need to install [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like having the "#" in there was the problem (see @patrix's answer and my comment). Although I still get an error, even as Admin. Would Distribute maybe help with that?

Comment: ah, didn't even think someone would enter that as a command.

Comment: lol. I did warn it was a super n00b question :) Any idea why I would get a permission error, even as admin?

Comment: Just because you're an admin, it doesn't automatically mean every command is run with admin permissions. This is similar to trying to delete something from the Applications folder. It'll prompt for your password. This is effectively the same as what the terminal is doing. Running with sudo, as per my other comment, gives it the privileges it needs.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen your sudo comment before I commented